how to add 'OR' condition in Wildcard file path in Synapse
I am trying to filter files containing str or containing stn.
if i type -str in the wildcard file path it returns me files containing str
and if type -stn, it returns me files containing stn
how can I get both files containing -str & -stn?
If Regex worked I could filter by this "-(str|stnu)"
But it returned me nothing

There is no option to use multiple wildcards , however , you can use Filter activity to check for the availibility of multiple file formats using expressions like @or(contains(item().name,'str'),contains(item().name,'stnu')) as per your requirement

similar thread :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1005237/how-to-use-multiple-wildcard-(filename-extensions)
